# Ways of failing http request after 200 response header sent

Tags: node.js, http, express, websocket, xmlhttprequest

**Question in short:**

Consider a case of long-lasting responses, when there is a lot of data to send. Then the server needs to transmit the data back to the client before finishing generating all the data. This requires sending http headers in the very beginning if I'm right. But if an exception raises during streaming the data, what is the best way to communicate this to the client? Ideally, I would like `XMLHttpRequest` in the browser to fail with non-200 response code or something similar. I'm using nodejs express on the server.

**Question in detail:**

I need to stream a lot of data into the browser, about 700Mb. I need to stream the data to the client while the data is being generated and not buffer it on the server, because otherwise server will run out of memory.

Here's a code that I'm using on the browser side.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', this.getDownloadLink(), true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', this.getAuthToken());
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      saveAsFile(xhr.response);
      resolve();
    }
    else {
      reject(xhr.response);
    }
  };
  xhr.onerror = () => {
    reject(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
});
```

I'm using XHR because I need to set authorization header. The browser is ok with keeping 700Mb before saving the file, probably because it stores blob on the disk, this is not a blocker.

So I start transmitting not knowing it will end with success. Then how do I communicate an error from server to client if data generation fails in the middle? **I would like the promise above to reject when server fails.**

Here's the part of the code I'm using on the server:

```
response.status(200);
db.stream
.on('data', data => response.write())
.on('error', error => {
  // this does not work as intended
  response.status(500);
  response.end(error.message);
})
```

As you can see, it's piping the data after the headers are sent.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way of sending "headers" at the end of response. They are called [Trailers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer).

You can send them using nodejs [Response object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_addtrailers_headers).

Answer (score 1):

Headers are sent and that's it, no turn point. Client doesn't receive the whole 700mb http response at once, it receives it piece by piece. If we read a http response as a plaintext, the first part of it will be metadata(status etc.) and the very headers row by row. This is the reason why it's impossible to sent 500 status after you already sent 200. Not because Node.js or express doesn't allow it, but because the very http as a protocol of communication doesn't allow it. 
I can see that you're using http to transfer this amount of data, because you need a header for your business logic. I recommend you to take a look on socket.io. It allows you to take some useful info/data from the query string, where you can put your data, which you are using the header for, as a query param and access it via socket.io node api! Quite handy to perform any authentication or related stuff.
Hope I helped you!